# can we give time after inserting data in mysql table using sequelize js node

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i created an order table in MySQL with fields like `start time`, `close time`, using these fields i need to give a time for inserting data in orders table after inserting data into orders table.

is it possible to do.

If yes please help me how to solve it.

Comment: Please explain by giving an example of what you want in the table

Answer (score 0):

With respect, your question leaves us guessing what you want to do.

You can insert the present time into a row by doing something like this:

```
  INSERT INTO orders (start_time, col1, col2) 
         VALUES (NOW(), 'something', 'another thing');
```

You can update a row to set the present time like this

```
  UPDATE orders SET close_time=NOW(), col2='some value'
   WHERE col1='something';
```

By declaring the start_time row like this you can cause the present time to be set automatically upon insert:

```
start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

But you probably need to set the close_time yourself according to the logic of your business.

If your `start_time` and `close_time` columns are defined with the `TIMESTAMP` data type you gain some advantages when dealing with multiple time zones.

(start_time, col1, col2) VALUES (NOW(), 'something', 'another thing');

Comment: hii jones... tanks for the response

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WqJVp9D3 please check the link where i mentioned my question clearly

Comment: Please ask another question, and include everything in your pastebin in the text of the question.